# Where is the Source for Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I got one excel sheet where the datas are pivoted. How can i found the source for the pivot table?

> From which datas the pivot table is made of?

My excel contains so many tabs and so many columns in each. Its hard for me figure this out. Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at menu item "Change data source". If the reference in it does not lead to any ranges in workbook then it means the original data source is removed.

Anyway, pivot table by default caches the original data in itself (unless "Save data with file" option was unchecked). You can extract the original data by removing ALL filters and double-clicking on the grand total value in your pivot table.